# ArcPy Cannot import name metadata

Tags: arcpy, metadata, importerror

I am using ArcGIS 10.5 and i am trying to get metadata information of a featureclass by calling following statement from arcpy within the ArcGIS Environment.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import metadata as md
```

But i am getting following error

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name metadata
```

Do i need to enable some extension or import this library some other way to make this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you may be following a [code sample for the `metadata` module of ArcPy](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/metadata/metadata-class.htm#C_GUID-ED041163-664D-4982-9CBC-86A9F2332D11) which is only available to work with the ArcGIS Pro (and not ArcMap) application of ArcGIS Desktop, and only since ArcGIS Pro 2.5 was released:

> The Metadata class allows you to access an item's metadata, and export
>   metadata to a standard metadata format. If you have appropriate
>   privileges, the class allows you to modify an item's metadata, or
>   import a standard-format metadata XML file's content to an item.

Consequently, to follow that or a similar code sample you need to be working with ArcGIS Pro at its version 2.5 or later.

To do something similar with ArcMap using a third party Python module see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/121771/115) to [Programmatically edit/update metadata in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5983).

Comment: Thats exactly what happened. I saw the sample of metadata module. 
I will use ArcGIS Pro now.

Comment: This helped my question as well. I'm not on Pro 2.5 yet. Evidently the metadata module isn't in 2.4.